Configure tigervnc-xorg-extension to listen only localhost
I need help to configure tigervnc-xorg-extension in localhost only.
I have tried to save $localhost = "yes"; in /etc/vnc.conf as mentioned in VNC Server is accessible only for localhost, but not working, also tried to put it on $HOME/.vnc/config.
I have installed tigervnc-xorg-extension in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
The documentation for this package is very minimal, but finally I can connect to with configure the xorg.conf with:
Section "Module"
        ...
        Load  "vnc"
EndSection
...
Section "Screen"
        ...
        Option     "SecurityTypes" "None"
EndSection

After reboot the X, there's process Xorg listen on 0.0.0.0:5900, as the VNC server.
Anyone know how to configure the tigervnc for xorg, where is the configuration should be placed?
I appreciate your help.

several minutes after I ran through the configuration /etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults, I just realized that if the configuration $SecurityTypes = "VncAuth" translated into Option     "SecurityTypes" "None", it means the configuration for $localhost = "yes".
So I changed the xorg.conf to:
Section "Module"
        ...
        Load  "vnc"
EndSection
...
Section "Screen"
        ...
        Option     "SecurityTypes" "None"
        Option     "localhost" "yes"
EndSection


that's the answer, no other configuration is needed.
